XCTestにてsystemName: でセットしたImage部品のlabelを確認しようとすると全く別の名前が取得される原因を知りたい
こちらでの質問は初めてなので文章が拙いでしょうがご容赦いただけると幸いです。
バージョン14.5(macOS Sonoma)がインストールされているMacBook Proの端末にて、
iOSアプリを作成しております。
Xcodeのバージョンは15.4、SwiftUIでの開発になります。
とある画面に、プロパティのBool値によってImageにセットする画像をcircle←→checkmark.circle.fillと切り替える、以下のようなカスタムチェックボックスを配置しました。
struct CustomCheckBox: View {

    @Binding var isCheck: Bool

    var body: some View {
        Image(systemName: isCheck ? "checkmark.circle.fill" : "circle")
            .onTapGesture {
                isCheck.toggle()
            }
    }
}

そしてその画面の自動化テストケースを作成するにあたり、
カスタムチェックボックスをタップする前後に、画面に配置したImageにセットされている画像名を取得し、その名前によって、画面の状態が正しく切り替わっていることを確認するコードを記述しました。
import XCTest

final class View0001UITests: XCTestCase {

    func testSwitchCheckbox() throws {
        let app = XCUIApplication()
        app.launch()
        sleep(3)
        let cells = app.collectionViews.cells
        let idx = Int.random(in: 0..<cells.count)
        let cell = cells.element(boundBy: idx)
        /// チェックされていないのを確認
        XCTAssertEqual(cell.images.firstMatch.label, "circle")
        cell.tap()
        /// チェックされているのを確認
        XCTAssertEqual(cell.images.firstMatch.label, "checkmark.circle.fill")
    }

ところが、上記のコードの最後は失敗し、
Swift.print("ラベル:" + cell.images.firstMatch.label)

でカスタムチェックボックスのラベルを調べてみると、
ラベル:Selected

と出てきました。

なぜcheckmark.circle.fillという名前のシンボルが突然Selectedに変わってしまったのでしょうか。
原因を知りたいです。
以上よろしくお願いいたします。

後々調べましたところ、どうやらAppleのアクセシビリティ機能により、一部の画像にはわかりやすいキーワードのようなものが紐づいており、特にAccessibilityIdentifierを設定していないとそちらの方で出てくるようでした。XcodeのAccessibility Inspectorという機能を使うと、その内容を確かめられるようです。
